# Server Pending Reboot

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I am trying to modify my PowerShell script to find the best possible ways to check for Pending Reboots on our servers. This script checks the registry entries. However, I am seeing inconsistencies from other PowerShell scripts and wanting guidance on the best approach.

```
function PendingReboot ($comp) {
process {
    try {
        $WMI_OS = ""
        $RegCon  = ""
        $WMI_OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $comp -ErrorAction Stop
        if ($?){
        try{ 
            $RegCon = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"LocalMachine",$comp) 
            If ($WMI_OS.BuildNumber -ge 6001){ 
                $RegValueSetupex = ""
                $RegValuePFRO2k8 = ""
                $RegSubKeySM = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\") 
                $RegValueSetupex = $RegSubKeySM.GetValue("SetupExecute",$null) 
                if ($RegValueSetupex){
                    $RegValueSetupex = $true
                }
                
                $RegSubKeySM = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\") 
                $RegValuePFRO2k8 = $RegSubKeySM.GetValue("PendingFileRenameOperations",$null) 
                if ($RegValuePFRO2k8 ){
                    $RegValuePFRO2k8  = $true
                }
                
                $RegCon.Close()
                
                if ( $RegValueSetupex -eq $true -or $RegValuePFRO2k8 -eq $true){
                    return '<font color="#FF0000">'+$true
                }
                else {
                    return $false                           
                }
            }
            else{   
                $RegValuePFRO2k3 = $false;
                $RegCon = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"LocalMachine","$comp") 
                $RegSubKeySM = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\") 
                $RegValuePFRO2k3 = $RegSubKeySM.GetValue("PendingFileRenameOperations",$null) 
                $RegCon.Close()
                If ($RegValuePFRO2k3) { 
                    return  '<font color="#FF0000">'+$true; 
                }
                else {
                    return $false; 
                } 
            }
        
        }
        catch {
            return '<font color="#FFFF00">'+"Remote Registry Service KO"
        }
        }
        else {
            throw $error[0].Exception
        }
    }   
    catch {
            return '<font color="#FF0000">'+"RPC Issue"         
    }
}
```

}

Comment: while i have never used it, this seems to cover a broad range mod places to check ... >>> How to Check for a Pending Reboot in the Registry (Windows) — https://adamtheautomator.com/pending-reboot-registry-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function PendingBoot($comp) {

    $pendingRebootTests = @(
        @{
            Name = 'RebootPending'
            Test = { Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing'  Name 'RebootPending' -ErrorAction Ignore }
            TestType = 'ValueExists'
        }
        @{
            Name = 'RebootRequired'
            Test = { Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update'  Name 'RebootRequired' -ErrorAction Ignore }
            TestType = 'ValueExists'
        }
        @{
            Name = 'PendingFileRenameOperations'
            Test = { Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager' -Name 'PendingFileRenameOperations' -ErrorAction Ignore }
            TestType = 'NonNullValue'
        }
    )


    $session = New-PSSession -Computer SRV1
    foreach ($test in $pendingRebootTests) {
        $result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $test.Test
        if ($test.TestType -eq 'ValueExists' -and $result) {
            $true
        } elseif ($test.TestType -eq 'NonNullValue' -and $result -and $result.($test.Name)) {
            $true
        } else {
            $false
        }
    }
    $session | Remove-PSSession

}
```